# How to use multiple database function for the same column? OBIEE 11.1.1.9.0

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, repository, obiee, evaluate

I have a problem with my repository. My Oracle Business Intelligence version is 11.1.1.9.0, and I try to use two different function in same column on my repository.

**Example:**

```
EVALUATE('DB_function1(DB_function2(%1))' AS VARCHAR(100), "SUBJECT_AREA"."SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"."MY_COLUMN")
```

But I recive these errors when I use AGGREGATION FUNCTIONS (like COUNT);

```
Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43119. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 17001. [nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 979, message: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression at OCI call OCIStmtExecute. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 17010. [nQSError: 17010] SQL statement preparation failed. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT 0 s_0, "SUBJECT_AREA"."TABLE_NAME"."MY_COLUMN_TEXT" s_1, COUNT(DISTINCT "SUBJECT_AREA"."TABLE_NAME"."MY_COLUMN_XY") s_2 FROM "SUBJECT_AREA" FETCH FIRST 100000001 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, nested aggregation may be? Try EVALUATE_AGGR. See documentation for reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/appsql.htm#BIEUG674

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to this query:

```
SELECT 0 s_0, "CITYPLUS"."ARS_DOSYA"."DOSYA_TASFIYE_DURUM" s_1, 
COUNT(DISTINCT "CITYPLUS"."ARS_DOSYA"."DOSYA_ID") s_2 
FROM "CITYPLUS" 
FETCH FIRST 100000001 ROWS ONLY
```

you have some fields and a count without any aggregation. You should add a

```
GROUP BY 0 s_0, "CITYPLUS"."ARS_DOSYA"."DOSYA_TASFIYE_DURUM" s_1
```

Comment: I don't have permission to change query. I create a business intelligence model and then I create analysis with drag and drop. So I can't add GROUP BY 0 s_0, "CITYPLUS"."ARS_DOSYA"."DOSYA_TASFIYE_DURUM" s_1 to query.

Comment: @yagmurdursun one of the 2 functions contains that error if you don't fix it you'll never be able to use that function. Maybe you made some mistake configuring one of the drag and drop block and that caused the messed up query.

Comment: no they are not. I am sure about function because if I don't use aggregation functions it works, but when I use it doesn't work.

Comment: If it's not in the functions where is that select? You said you are launching the **EVALUATE(....)**

Comment: Do you know about Oracle Business Intelligence? Have you developed any model? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: No, never used. But I think that it could be a model configuration problem, the tool should be hyper tested and it's hard that it contains a bug like that

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution for anyone if she/he has same problem with OBIEE 11g; I couldn't find a solution. I solved my problem by using "case" clause after first function result.